# How to efficiently count hits of a list of points in a list of intervals in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, performance, intervals

I have a list of about 50,000 points between 0 and 250,000,000 and a list of about 10,000,000 intervals. The intervals are stored in a MySQL database in 12 tables.

I want to count for each point how many intervals surround it. I tried several methods to do this but I always get problems. If I want to build an interval tree it needs to much memory and simply iterate over the lists needs to much time.

I need the result within about 10 seconds after I get a list of points. Additionally it wouldn't be a problem to prepare the database or create a data structure. Therefore it would be ok if this takes much more time under the condition that this preparation only have to be done once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do your 50 000 points always remain the same? Or do you mean that you need to return the interval counts for 50 000 new points in 10 seconds?

Comment: @MickMnemonic No they are allways different. The intervals are allways the same but the points differ every call. And yes I want to return the interval counts for every point of the 50,000 points in maximal 10 seconds.

Comment: Do the intervals overlap?  If yes, you have a mess.  If no, then I may have a trick for you.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to cache the table of intervals?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Yes they overlap and some intervals are duplicated too but they have to be counted both. 12 tables because they are obtained from another MySQL database and are categorized in different contents. Each table has about 12 columns but I only need two of them. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for these two columns are `'chromStart' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` and the same for second column `'chromEnd'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No simple solution**. There is (I believe) no straightforward way to perform the query without scanning at least half of each table.  The "half" comes from having `INDEX(Start), INDEX(End)` and hoping that the optimizer will pick the better index dynamically.  This is "Order(N)".

**Buckets**. By inventing "buckets" and deciding which intervals lie in which bucket (or buckets), you could search for a point by asking which single bucket it is in, then scanning just within that bucket for the Start..End.  `INDEX(bucket, start), INDEX(bucket, end)`.  However, it does require duplicating some rows (since an interval might span multiple buckets).  It is a partial improvement on the performance, and involves some complexity in inserts and selects.  The number of buckets becomes a tradeoff between speed and space.

**Non-overlapping**. If you could turn it into non-overlapping intervals, then there is a much better way and is Order(1).  [Reference](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).  It does involve complexity in inserts and selects, but Stored Routines can hide such.

**13th table**. If you go with buckets or non-overlapping, it *may* be better to have a 13th table for the search, thereby confining the complexity to that table without messing with the existing 12.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with files.

1. Create a file with 20 million records listing locations of endpoints, and whether going from left to right you have +1 interval (start of interval), or -1 interval (end of interval)
2. Sort this file by location.
3. Run through the file ONCE, and emit for each location a record with the location, how many endpoints to its left, and how many if you are at that point.
4. Put the contents of that file in the database, with a BTREE index.

Now for each point you can use the index to find the record with the last location larger than or equal to your point.  And then access the correct field depending on that.

If you can't coax MySQL to do this in time, you can use BerkeleyDB to implement the BTREE and just do that.  Or heck, you can *probably* just sort your points then scan that file in parallel with the 20 million point file.  (I'd try BerkeleyDB first.)